# EAddrInUse for live reload - node js - on running gulp command

Tags: node.js, port, gulp, livereload

I run gulp for my mean-io stack application.

I get the below error.

```
13:15:54] Starting 'server'...
13:15:54] Finished 'server' after 47 ms
13:15:54] Live reload server listening on: 35729

.. Uhoh. Got error listen EADDRINUSE ...
rror: listen EADDRINUSE
   at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
   at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
   at listen (net.js:1061:10)
   at Server.listen (net.js:1127:5)
```

I guess the port 35729 is being used by some other application. Am I right? I have also tried changing the port number in livereload.js. But then, I got the same error.

The below are the files where, I see the 35729 port number assigned. Please let me know if should change the port number any where.

```
 myApp\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\node_modules\tiny-lr-fork\lib\public\livereload.js:
321:     this.port = 35829;                
myApp\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\node_modules\tiny-lr-fork\lib\server.js
20:   options.port = parseInt(options.port || 35729, 10);             
myApp\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\node_modules\tiny-lr-fork\node_modules\noptify\index.js:
21: //       .option('port', '-p', 'Port to listen on (default: 35729)', Number)        
myApp\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\node_modules\tiny-lr-fork\bin\tiny-lr:
14:   .option('port', '-p', 'Port to listen on (default: 35729)', Number)
18: opts.port = opts.port || 35729;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a change in `gulpexpress/index.js`, port number changed to 35829. And it worked.

It seems same port number 35729 is used more than once for two different process.

Answer (score 10):

When working with `gulp`, I've found that sometimes terminating my process will fail to close a connection on the `livereload` port 35729. This leaves an open file descriptor listening on that port, which will make it hard to start my server up again, because `gulp` will complain as soon as it starts up `livereload`.

Sometimes you don't know the name of the process that owns the connection, so it's hard to find and kill. To list files opened by processors that are listening on a port using TCP, you can use the `lsof -n -i4TCP:#####` command. In this case, you get:

```
$ lsof -n -i4TCP:35729
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    15723  testuser   24u  IPv6 0x71823b3990749ea5      0t0  TCP *:35729 (LISTEN)
```

Now you have the PID of the process that's listening on the port you're trying to access, so you can kill this with

```
$ kill -9 15723
```

and now running `gulp` should work just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Port `35729` used by (gulp-express) `tiny-lr` livereload server. You need to disable `tiny-lr` livereload server.

Instead of

```
server.run(['app.js']);
```

You can do this when starting server:

```
server.run(['app.js'], {}, false|35729|{});
```

`false` mean that `tiny-lr` livereload server disabled.

Comment: In which file this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows, you can use `netstat -aon` to see what port is in use (ie listening, established).  This also provides the process ID of each item listed.

[image]

In the screenshot below the port is used (or listened on) by a process with PID 10968.

Open up your **Task Manager**, then go to the **Details** tab and look for that same PID.  Click on **End Task** and then restart your app using `npm start`.

It should launch.